# Why when creating 4 walls dynamic in the update two walls height lower then the two others ?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallsTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform prefab;
    public float wallsSize;
    public Vector3 wallsStartPosition;

    private List<Transform> walls = new List<Transform>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Transform go = Instantiate(prefab);
            go.transform.parent = transform;
            go.transform.localPosition = wallsStartPosition;
            walls.Add(go);
        }

        walls[2].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(wallsStartPosition.x + wallsSize, 0, wallsStartPosition.z + wallsSize);
        walls[3].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(wallsStartPosition.x + wallsSize, 0, wallsStartPosition.z + wallsSize);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { // transform.localScale.z != wallsSize
        if (walls[0].transform.position.x != wallsSize && walls[0].transform.localScale.z != wallsSize
            && walls[1].transform.position.x != wallsSize && walls[1].transform.localScale.z != wallsSize)
        {
            walls[0].transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
            walls[0].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);

            walls[1].transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
            walls[1].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        }

        if (walls[2].transform.position.x != -wallsSize && walls[2].transform.localScale.z != -wallsSize
            && walls[3].transform.position.x != -wallsSize && walls[3].transform.localScale.z != -wallsSize)
        {
            walls[2].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
            walls[2].transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);

            walls[3].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
            walls[3].transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is in the end the walls not same height and width. They are missed by 0.5

The walls values in the end:

```
Wall 0: X = 49.5 Y = 49.5 Z = 0    
Wall 1: X = 0 Y = 49.5 Z = 49.5
Wall 2: X = 49.5 Y = 50 Z = 100
Wall 3: X = 100 Y = 50 Z = 49.5
```

How can i fix it so all the walls will be same height and width ?

Second problem is if there is a better way shorter way to write this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, the 0.5 miss is due to the different starting value of localsize([-10,1],[1,10]) and localposition([-10,0],[0,10]).

I have modified your code like following, hope this can help.
(I delete all Y-offset, you can add it back as you wish)

```
public Transform prefab;
public float wallsSize;
public Vector3 wallsStartPosition;

private List<Transform> walls = new List<Transform>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Transform go = Instantiate(prefab);
        go.transform.parent = transform;
        go.transform.localPosition = wallsStartPosition;
        walls.Add(go);
    }

    walls[2].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(wallsStartPosition.x + wallsSize, 0, wallsStartPosition.z + wallsSize);
    walls[3].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(wallsStartPosition.x + wallsSize, 0, wallsStartPosition.z + wallsSize);

    walls[0].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
    walls[1].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    walls[2].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
    walls[3].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0.5f);

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{ // transform.localScale.z != wallsSize

    if (walls[0].transform.localScale.z < wallsSize && walls[1].transform.localScale.z < wallsSize)
    {
        walls[0].transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        walls[1].transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
        walls[0].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
        walls[1].transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    }

    if (walls[2].transform.localScale.z > -wallsSize && walls[3].transform.localScale.z > -wallsSize)
    {
        walls[2].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        walls[3].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0, 1, 1);
        walls[2].transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
        walls[3].transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Now, the result is like this:
[image]

Comment: Ok but now half of the walls on Y axis is under the terrain.  The reason i used the y offset 0.5 and -0.5 is to keep it raising on one side up only.

Comment: @HenAvrami, you can modify the y-axis value in Vector3 as you wish. the reason I make it all Zero is only for easy test. I have modified the code a little bit to fix this issue. Hope this can help.